# Color syntax highlighting working on one system but not the others. Same nanorc file

Tags: configuration, editors, syntax-highlighting, nano, rc

I'm trying to set my color syntax highlighting in `nano`, but it doesn't work as expected.

1. One system everything works. This is an Fedora 21 laptop.
2. Two systems everything I've tried except `man something` works. This
   is an Fedora 21 desktop and an Fedora 21 vm in VirtualBox.
3. One system only one file I've tried works(opening nanorc itself gives highlighting). This is an Debian Wheezy
   desktop.

If I do `man emacs` it only works as expected on one system. I also have syntax highlighting for many other types of files, **I thought the only thing I needed to set this up was to have** `.nanorc` located in the users home directory so `nano` could find it. This is very confusing.

I've tried to look for differences in `bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, `bashrc` but nothing stands out and maybe that's irrelevant. I've looked at the permissions. I've started an new terminal and restarted the system.

Here is a piece from my `.nanorc` file:

```
#####################################################################

## Manpages
##include "/usr/share/nano/man.nanorc"

## Here is an example for manpages.
##
syntax "man" "\.[1-9]x?$"
color green "\.(S|T)H.*$"
color brightgreen "\.(S|T)H" "\.TP"
color brightred "\.(BR?|I[PR]?).*$"
color brightblue "\.(BR?|I[PR]?|PP)"
color brightwhite "\\f[BIPR]"
color yellow "\.(br|DS|RS|RE|PD)"

#####################################################################
```

**Questions:**

Why is the same `.nanorc` file not working the same on four Linux systems(Fedora 21 is working, two Fedora 21 not working and Debian Wheezy not working at all). What am I missing?

What are the steps to set a custom `.nanorc` file to be used by nano and be sure it's not in some kind of conflict or something?

### --------------------------------------------

Here is the **full nanorc** file on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/DJ3jk67y).

Comment: Having a similar problem. I have the includes uncommented. I even downloaded new syntax highlighting files from the GitHub project https://github.com/tech4david/nano-highlight. In Nano, my .nanorc file has colors, but none of my Bash scripts do. I've even tried specifying the syntax with `--syntax=`. I noticed that nano is compiled with `--enable-colors` so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I since found that there is a bug in **nano < 2.7.4-1**

***nano: /etc/nanorc is ignored, if ~/.nanorc exists***

> Latest from the bug report:
>
> I just made the dist-upgrade to Debian 9.0,
> which included an update of package nano to version 2.7.4-1
> and the problem vanished, the bug is solved in 2.7.4-1.

The bug report:
[bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=743179)

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting the `include` paths should do it.

eg. `##include "/usr/share/nano/c.nanorc"` has comments in front of `include "...`. Remove the comments and open a c/c++ file; the text should be highlighted. Do this for all the other includes you want.

Comment: This is probably not the case/problem as this is from the same nanorc file on all systems, it works perfectly on one of them, and it also has those lines commented out.